# How can I get two scroll bars to scroll at the same time with jQuery and .on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a suggestion to add this to my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('scroll', '.wrapper1', function () {
        $(".wrapper2").scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
    });
    $(document).on('scroll', '.wrapper2', function () {
        $(".wrapper1").scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
    });
</script>
```

So I could change two scroll bars at together. Here's the HTML that I am using:

```
<div class="wrapper1">
   <div class="div1">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
   <div class="div2">
      <div data-ng-class="{'hidden': loading!=0 }"
         data-ng-form="gridForm">
         <table class="form grid table" style="height: 600px; width: 1500px;">
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have jQuery loaded but it seems that the scroll bars don't scroll together. Can anyone help suggest why this is.

Note I need to use .on as the scroll bar area is loaded dynamically.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/npwD8/

Comment: Unless that's just a typo you made in this post. Does scrolling `wrapper1` work as expected?

Comment: Thanks. I just corrected that, crossed my fingers and it's the same. Neither track each other. I also tried a breakpoint INSIDE the functions but they never seem to be called althought the scripts do get run at the start.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/npwD8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scroll()` event is unqualified to use event bubbling;

> "In all browsers, the `load`, `scroll`, and `error` events (e.g., on an `<img>`
>   element) do not bubble." - [**jQuery on() documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Therefore event delegation (e.g. `$(document).on('...', '...')`) isn't possible with it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

I've updated your example on JSFiddle to one that works, though I am not certain it will ultimately fit your use case.

http://jsfiddle.net/npwD8/4/

```
$('.wrapper').on('scroll', function({
    $(".wrapper").not(this).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

The scroll event does not bubble, so delegating down from window won't work. You'll need to manually handle the attachment of these events when those elements are added to the DOM.