# How can I link the scrolling of two divs that are dynamically loaded without using .on?

Tags: javascript

I would like to link the scrolling of the wrapper1 and wrapper2:

```
  <div class="wrapper1">
       <div class="div1">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
       <div class="div2">
          <div data-ng-class="{'hidden': loading!=0 }"
             data-ng-form="gridForm">
             <table class="form grid table" style="height: 600px; width: 1500px;">
             </table>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

The above is loaded dynamically and from what I have read I cannot use the .on jQuery method with scroll. So I would like to use something like this:

```
<div id="mydiv" onscroll='myMethod();'>

function myMethod(){ alert(1); }
```

Can someone give me some suggestions as to how I can make the scrolls work at the same time using the onscroll call and methods?

Please note that this is not a duplicate question to:

[How can I get two scroll bars to scroll at the same time with jQuery and .on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201824/how-can-i-get-two-scroll-bars-to-scroll-at-the-same-time-with-jquery-and-on)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get two scroll bars to scroll at the same time with jQuery and .on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201824/how-can-i-get-two-scroll-bars-to-scroll-at-the-same-time-with-jquery-and-on)

Comment: Please check the answer to this question before marking as a duplicate. Note that I am asking to not do it with .on for the reason that it's not possible. Thank you.

Comment: What do you think `on` does, and why do think you'll be able to do it without it if it impossible with?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand what you said in your comment but please note the accepted answer "It's not possible with .on". When I use the ".on" I refer to the jQuery ".on" not to the first two characters of the word "onscroll".

Comment: The accepted answer says it's not possible with event delegation. Handlers bound with `on` are not necessarily delegated.

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cannot-use-delegate-for-scroll-events

Comment: I'm not disputing that; see the answer: __You will have to bind the event handler to the dynamically created element yourself.__

Comment: You need to run the code [in Jay's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20202800/7469) _after_ dynamically inserting the elements.

Comment: The problem is I do not know how to bind the event handler to the dynamically created element. That's what the question is trying to ask.

Comment: Then you should show the code for how the element is being added to the DOM so we can show you where to attach the handlers.

Comment: Why can't you just use the inline event? Yes it is "bad practice", but it should work fine. You are asking the wrong question, you should be asking how in angular can I detect when the content is done loading. I am not expert, but it has something to do with onFinishRender